# Python Builder Load file Strange error

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy

When I run this code it gives me following error.(though main.kv is in the same path).

this is the error>>

> return mainwindow()  TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

and this is the code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import*

mainwindow = Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class KivyTest(App):
     def build(self):
     self.title="Kivy App Learning"
     return mainwindow()



x=KivyTest()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    x.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the parentheses. Just try this (plus fixing indentation as per the other answers):

```
class KivyTest(App):
     def build(self):
         self.title="Kivy App Learning"
         return mainwindow
```

Comment: This is correct, but also mainwindow is None. Presumably the kv file doesn't include a kv file definition.

Comment: No window is created. Terminating application run.

Comment: @inclement thanks for the follow up. I agree, sounds like there's something wrong with the kv file too. We may need to see that too to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: The kivy file is empty dude.

Comment: I don't think so. Your kv file is empty, so the `mainwindow` variable becomes `None`. This means your `build` method also returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is happening because of its indented code

Try this:

```
class KivyTest(App):
     def build(self):
         self.title="Kivy App Learning"
         return mainwindow()
```

Comment: I tried using correct indentation still no success.